# How to display all the tabcontent in single tab menu(ALL)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

This is the example of tab menu please check below, what I'm trying to do when I clicked the button `ALL` it will display all the `tabcontent` and each tab content has its own tab menu. TIA!

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}


/* Fade in tabs */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    </head><body><div class="tab"><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'All')">All</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button></div><div id="All" class="tabcontent"></div><div id="London" class="tabcontent"><h3>London</h3><p>London is the capital city of England.</p></div><div id="Paris" class="tabcontent"><h3>Paris</h3><p>Paris is the capital of France.</p></div><div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent"><h3>Tokyo</h3><p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition in the beginning for the "All" arguments and display all tabcontent

See code snippet

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {

  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  if (cityName === 'All') {

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
    }

  } else {

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";

  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}


/* Fade in tabs */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'All')">All</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="All" class="tabcontent">

</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Chiler is it possible to display all tabcontent without clicking the `ALL` menu? let say once the page are loaded the all menu tabcontent are already displayed?

Comment: @cachess do you mean when first loaded, yes you can by changing the initial css of tabcontent from `display:none` to `display:block ` see my update

Comment: thanks for helping me out though I tried to `display:block` when first loaded using javascript but its not working but anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the content and tab content their own ids.  Then cause the tab dropdown to become active after the tab in the menu is clicked.  What it looks like to me at the moment is that you are trying to  activate everything all at once.

I personally would use classes for this instead of ids for the sake of selection.

Answer (score 0):

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

Give the button with the '*All*' an id of id="*defaultOpen*" **THEN**  add the above line outside the onClick function like this

```
<script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Hope it helps. Here is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_open)